# Jersey Client + Multipart form data + MessageBodyWriter issue

Tags: android, jersey, jax-rs, multipartform-data

I'm having an issue with a Multipart-form-data POST request using the Jersey Client API on Android. I've been following various examples on the web and they are all fairly similar in regards to the implementation.

```
Client client = createClientInstance();
WebResource r = client.resource(BASEURL).path("DataUpload");
ClientResponse post;
try {
    FormDataMultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
    multiPart.field("account", account);
    multiPart.field("checksum", checksum);
    multiPart.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("file", file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE));
    post = r.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        .post(ClientResponse.class, multiPart);

} catch (ClientHandlerException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
} finally {
    client.destroy();
}
```

When I execute this code on my device, I am presented with an exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No MessageBodyWriter for body part of type 'java.io.File' and media type 'application/octet-stream'
```

I thought Jersey was supposed to handle File objects without any extra configuration. Removing the bodypart line will allow Jersey to make the request but that eliminates the point of this.

I have these libraries on my buildpath (which were pulled in with Maven):

- jersey-client-1.14
- jersey-core-1.14
- jersey-multipart-1.14
- mimepull-1-6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710953/trasferring-files-and-data-with-jersey should help?

Comment: It seems my problem was related to the improper loading of the Jersey classes by Android. I was using the workaround that was listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342506/jersey-client-on-android-nullpointerexception/10676918#10676918) but that solution was incomplete as it was not loading all the classes required for my application. When I added the [complete class that was originally listed](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/java-lang-NullPointerException-on-Android-tt4212447.html#a5459910), it was able to do the file upload.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two things to try:

1. remove the MIME type from the FileDataBodyPart construction to see if Jersey can find a mime type it is happy to default to :

   `multiPart.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("file", file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE));`
2. tell your client config about the multipart body writer (presumably inside your `createClientInstance()` method) :

   ```
   com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig config = new com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig();
   config.getClasses().add(MultiPartWriter.class);
   client = Client.create(config);
   ```

Hope that helps.