# Sending POST request to a webservice

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey

I want to send a POST request to test my local webservice. The request body is an XML body and i generated the classes using JAXB.

Everything is fine but when I execute the following code

```
ClientResponse response = service.path("api")
                    .path("v1")
                    .path("shipments")
                    .path("package")
                    .path("order")
                    .path("status")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                    .post(ClientResponse.class, orderStatusRequest);
```

I get the following error

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class com.api.shipments.model.OrderStatusRequestType, and MIME media type, application/octet-stream, was not found
```

Can someone point me to a direction, what i am missing here?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832760/a-message-body-writer-for-java-type-class-mypackage-b-and-mime-media-type-app ?

Comment: Can you provide the signature of your server side method?

Comment: I think that `orderStatusRequest` String is not in a right xml format! can you share it also?

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. I figure it out long ago but didn't get chance to update this question. You can post it as a reply and i can accept your answer.