# Jersey Client issue for CXF Rest Service

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, cxf, jax-rs

I am trying to create a REST client for a REST method created using Apache CXF. I used wadl2java command to generate the DTO classes for the client, but they miss the @@XmlRootElement element and so I am trying to use the JAXB object factory, but getting issues.

Please verify my code and the Exception I get.

Source:
Person.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Address address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

SampleRestService.java

```
@POST
@Path("/sayHello")
public void sayHello(Person person) {
    System.out.println("Hello there!!!");
    System.out.println("Your name -> " + person.getName());     
}
```

Client Person.java created using wadl2java command:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "person", propOrder = {  
    "name"
})
public class Person {

    protected Address address;
    protected String name;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the address property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Address }
     *     
     */
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the address property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Address }
     *     
     */
    public void setAddress(Address value) {
        this.address = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the name property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the name property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

}
```

Jersey Client:

```
@Test
public void testSayHelloObjectFactory(){
   try {
    ObjectFactory objectFactory=new ObjectFactory();
    com.wk.client.data.Person person=objectFactory.createPerson();
    person.setName("Saravanan");

    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());        
           service.path("/sampleRestService").path("sayHello").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(person);
     } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Exception received ::

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class com.wk.client.data.Person, and MIME media type, application/octet-stream, was not found
```

Also additionally the below Resource class was created by wadl2java. What is the use of this?

```
@Path("/")
public interface Resource {

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/octet-stream")
    @Path("sayHello")
    void post();

}
```

Command used to generate the classes from WADL:

```
C:\apache-cxf-2.4.2\bin>wadl2java -p com.wk.rest.client http://localhost:8080/Re
stService/sampleRestService?_wadl&_type=xml

May 29, 2013 7:44:02 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBUtils logGeneratedClassNames
INFO: Created classes: generated.Address, generated.ObjectFactory, generated.Per
son
'_type' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Below is the WADL generated by CXF:

```
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><grammars><xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="Address" type="address"/>
<xs:element name="Person" type="person"/>
<xs:complexType name="person">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="address" type="address"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="address">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="city" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="streetName" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="streetNumber" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
</grammars><resources base="http://localhost:8080/RestService/sampleRestService"><resource path="/"><resource path="sayHello"><method name="POST"><request><representation mediaType="application/octet-stream"/></request><response status="204"></response></method></resource></resource></resources></application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You send a POST that waits for `application/octet-stream` in `Resource` class, but you send as `APPLICATION_XML` in your test case.

Another point is: The post method don't receive any parameter at constructor, so you need to declare the `Person` object to be processed to the Resource method.

Just delete the post() method at `Resource` class.

**[EDIT]**

I've found in this call:

```
service.path("/sampleRestService").path("sayHello").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(person)
```

the correct is to specify the type of the entity, like:

```
service.path("/sampleRestService").path("sayHello").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(Person.class, person)
```

Comment: I commented the post method in the generated resource class, but still I get this Exception - `A message body writer for Java type, class com.wk.client.data.Person, and MIME media type, application/octet-stream, was not found`

Comment: this is because this generated class overrides your post method with different accepted types. it is possible to change this configuration or remove the annotations?

Comment: oh okay, is there an alternative where `APPLICATION_XML` will be generated in the post method and annotations corresponding to it, rather than `application/octet-stream`

Comment: Even if I change my client to use Octet-stream media type, its giving me the same error. `service.path("/sampleRestService").path("sayHello").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE).post(person);`

Comment: This is possible because you are sending via MediaType.APPLICATION_XML. can you edit your post and put the command line that you use to generate the service please?

Comment: Tried this but still getting same error - `service.path("/sampleRestService").path("sayHello").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(Person.class, person)`

Comment: Take a look on this issue that i've found with same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832760/a-message-body-writer-for-java-type-class-mypackage-b-and-mime-media-type-app
 . In this case they put the type() of the request.