# A message body reader for Java class java.util.List, and Java type java.util.List<>, and MIME media type text/html was not found

Tags: java, web-services

I got this error

```
A message body reader for Java class java.util.List, and Java type java.util.List<Entities.service.GroupU>, and MIME media type text/html was not found
```

when I execute this code

```
 GroupUClient client1 = new GroupUClient();
        ClientResponse response = client1.findAll_XML(ClientResponse.class);

        GenericType<List<GroupU>> genericType = new GenericType<List<GroupU>>() {
        };
// Returns an ArrayList of Players from the web service
        data = new ArrayList<GroupU>();
        data = (response.getEntity(genericType));
```

what is the problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832760/a-message-body-writer-for-java-type-class-mypackage-b-and-mime-media-type-app

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all generated classes and all restful classes and the GroupUClient  then the program works without problems.

change from

```
public ChatuserClient() {
    com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig config = new com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig();
    client = Client.create(config);
    webResource = client.resource(BASE_URI).path("entities.chatuser");
}
```

to

```
 public ChatuserClient() {
        com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig config = new com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig();
        client = Client.create(config);
        webResource = client.resource(BASE_URI).path("entities.service.chatuser");
    }
```

Comment: also I used Entities.service package for Entities and service package for services and clients package  for clients