# com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException

Tags: java, rest, junit, jersey, jersey-client

I'm using Jersey in my REST-application. I need to test it with junit. But I got an `com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException`. Stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/octet-stream ->
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider
*/* ->
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class        com.example.Student, and Java type class com.example.Student, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:561)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:517)
at com.example.servlet.StudentResourceTest.test(StudentResourseTest.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I do not know how to fix this bug. I'm looking forward to your help.
My code:

```
@Path("/student")
@Component
public class StudentResourse {
@Autowired
private StrudentService service;

@Path("/getStudent/{id}")
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Student getStudent(@PathParam("id") long id) {
    return service.get(id);
}  
}
```

This class works fine. When I type in browser: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Application/student/getStudent/100500` it shows me student in xml
My test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:configuration.xml")
@TestExecutionListeners({ DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class,
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
public class StudentResourseTest extends JerseyTest {

@Override
protected AppDescriptor configure() {
    return new WebAppDescriptor.Builder("com.example.servlet")
            .contextPath("context").build();
}

@Override
protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
    return new HTTPContainerFactory();
}

@Test
@DatabaseSetup("dataset.xml")
public void test() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
        ClientResponse response = service.path("getStudent").path("100500")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get(ClientResponse.class);
        Student student = (Student) response.getEntity(Student.class);
        System.out.println(student);
}

@Override
public URI getBaseURI() {
    return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/Application/student/")
            .build();
}
```

}

I'm using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-http</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Student class marked as @XmlRootElement. Problem is in test class. Any ideas? Thanks for you answers

Comment: Do you use even Jersey in version 1.2? Do you need to use such an old version or can you switch to the latest which is 1.17.1? What is the HTTP status of the received response?

Comment: It returns 404 Not Found. I do not know why, because it works in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're deploying your application to `context` context-path but then you're assuming (by overriding `getBaseURI()` method) that the application is deployed on `Application` context-path. Try to remove the overriding `getBaseURI()` method and change the test method to following:

```
@Test
@DatabaseSetup("dataset.xml")
public void test() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    ClientResponse response = resource()
        .path("students").path("getStudent").path("100500")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .get(ClientResponse.class);

    Student student = (Student) response.getEntity(Student.class);
    System.out.println(student);
}
```

Also check for HTTP response status (should be `200`) and response media-type (should be `application/xml` in this case - if you request `application/xml` and get `application/octet-stream` something is clearly wrong).

Answer (score 1):

using below annortation @XmlRootElement
and change library of jersey 
AND server log clean after publish the project

Answer (score 0):

Please check [A message body writer for Java type, class myPackage.B, and MIME media type, application/octet-stream, was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832760/a-message-body-writer-for-java-type-class-mypackage-b-and-mime-media-type-app)

& [this link](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e3746) to resolve your issue.I hope it is enough to sort out your problem.

Comment: the second link is not working (the anchor didn't exist anymore)