# How to pass JSON object to server from RESTful client in java

Tags: java, json, rest

I'm creating a web application. I want to do the admin operations using Java SE application. To do that I created a RESTful `ShoppingAdminClient` in my SE project. I need to pass an JSON object to the server from client. I tried with this,

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    ShoppingAdminClient sac = new ShoppingAdminClient();
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("itemName", "Itemms");
    sac.create_JSON(jo);

}
```

But I got the following exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class shoppingadmin.Item, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:563)
at shoppingadmin.ShoppingAdminClient.create_JSON(ShoppingAdminClient.java:69)
at shoppingadmin.ShoppingAdmin.main(ShoppingAdmin.java:27)
    Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class shoppingadmin.Item, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
at             com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:204)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:147)
... 6 more
Java Result: 1
```

How do I pass a JSON type object to server?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832760/a-message-body-writer-for-java-type-class-mypackage-b-and-mime-media-type-app this link might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Jersey client, you can create a Jersey [Client](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client.html) instance to post your JSON to the server. So in order to send in JSON format, you can use [Jackson JSON library](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) and it can be bundled with Jersey by adding Jersey-JSON jars. You also need to add Jersey client dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then your client code will look like:

```
public String requestResource(String baseURL, String path) {
        Client wsClient = Client.create();
        WebResource rs = wsClient.resource(baseURL);
        String response = rs.path(path).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(String.class, item);
        return response;

    }
```

Note that `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` in the `type` method specifies the data format. Here `item` contains the data you want to send to the server. Also, don't forget to put the following line in the `web.xml` so that all POJO classes will be automatically serialized to JSON.

```
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
```

Comment: Where do I set that dependencies? My client application is a Java SE Application. Thanks

Comment: And what are these `MyItem` and `item`?

Comment: Just add it in your pom.xml if you use Maven. Otherwise, you can download the jars manually.

Comment: `item` is the data you want to send to the server. It can be any POJO classes, e.g., `MyItem item = new MyItem();` where `MyItem` is the class you create for the data you want to send. It can be as simple as a map in your example `"itemName" -> "Itemms"`.

Comment: @tonga Can you explain what the `path`parameter should have. Is there a difference b/w `baseURL & path`

Comment: @09Q71AO534 The `path` parameter is the additional path in your URL after the baseURL, which is the web root context, such as www.example.com/myapp, if you set up your web app root context as `myapp`. So for example, www.example.com/myapp/item/123, the baseURL is www.example.com/myapp, and the path is /item/123.