# How to get form parameters as object in restful webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have a login form with two values name and password. I pass this value as in my rest service. I get this value in my rest service using `FormParam` annotation. But, my requirement is to get that values as a class. I tried below methodology. But it's not work and shows the compile time error:
`@Form cannot be resolved to a type.`

```
@POST
@Path("login")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String login(@Form User form) {
     return "Logged with " + form.email + " " + form.password;
}

public class User {

      @FormParam("email")
      private String email;

      @FormParam("password")
      private String password;

}
```

My form is

```
<form method="POST" action="rest/login">


Email Address: <input type="text" name="email">
<br>
Password: <input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit">


</form>
```

How to receive form value as object?

Comment: Try `@BeanParam` instead of `@Form` and your `@FormParam` annotations on the `User` class should work just fine. [Documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html). I haven't got the time to test it right now. Let me know if it works for you. If it does, I'll post this as an answer.

Comment: @Tom,compile error:BeanParam cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Which JAX-RS implementation are you using? Also, what version is it?

Comment: Ok, I don't think this annotation is available in a version this early. I'm afraid you'll have to extract these parameters separately and explicitly construct a `User` object. Or maybe switching to a newer version of Jersey is an option?

Comment: You can also try the method described [on this blog](http://avianey.blogspot.com/2011/12/exception-mapping-jersey.html), see the _Contextual object injection_ section.

Comment: have u tried request param ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use @RequestParam even if it is a composite Java object. So change this

```
 public String login(@Form User form)
```

to

```
 public String login(@RequestParam("form") User form)
```

You just need to send user details under "form" param from client.

Comment: compile error:RequestParam cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @Madhesh import javax.ws.rs.RequestParam;

Comment: @junad,import javax.ws.rs.RequestParam; this annotation is not present in javax.ws.rs package.i am using jersey version 1.16

Comment: @Madhesh indeed it is, check your jars.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is only to have the data in the form of an object, you can call your ReST service by passing a JSON request:

**ReST method**

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String login(User form) {
// access values from inputObject
form.getEmail();
form.getPassword();
}
```

**User class**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class User {

      private String email;
      private String password;

      //getters and setters

    }
```

You need to use Jackson feature for overcoming MessageBody related error. If you are using Jackson version 2.x BELOW, you'll need to register Jackson feature in your `web.xml` file.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

In case of Jackson version 2.x and above, only add Jackson 2.x jars. The above mentioned snippet won't be required in `web.xml`

Comment: SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class my.first.rest.User, and Java type class my.first.rest.User, and MIME media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded was not found.

Comment: Have you added `@XmlRootElement` to `User`?

Comment: Can you check the accepted answer to this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832760/a-message-body-writer-for-java-type-class-mypackage-b-and-mime-media-type-app

Comment: i call restful from html

Comment: If you are using Maven, try adding the dependency for `jersey-json`.

`<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>`

Check the version number as per your Jersey version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62408/discussion-between-pam-and-madhesh).